# Procedure to resume working on an existing git branch after switching back to master?

Tags: git, github

I recently switched to master and pulled the latest changes on a project. Master has all current branches merged, so I want to work from master's code. However, I also want to branch again to the branch I was working on from this latest master.

What is the proper procedure to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rebase your branch against master](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

If this is a good solution for you depends on the workflow in your organization but it should generally be fine as long as no one else is basing work off your branch.